# Using Setters with EventTriggers

Tags: wpf, button, triggers

I have a button and and event trigger.Trigger. I want to disable the Button after it is Clicked.
I'm getting this error:

> A value of Type Setter cannot be added to a collection or dictionary
>   of type TriggerActionCollection.

Why I can't set a property in the EventTrigger ?

Thank you

```
    <Button   Width="100" Height="50" >
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                     <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
               </EventTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Why? Just use the event `Button_Clicked`. You may not want to automatically disable the button all the time. What if inputs are not configured properly? At least inside the button click event handler you can make that determination.

Also, at some point you may want to re-enable the button.

Comment: @IAbstract Don't want to have any code behind (MVVM).

Comment: Good luck with that. Seems like an extremely limiting requirement. Am I correct in assuming then that you are not going to have a ViewModel? Isn't your VM instantiating the View? Your VM can subscribe to the button click event and use whatever data is available in the Model to determine whether or not to disable the button. The VM can, when conditions are met, re-enable the button. No code behind the view itself.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have a Command object that is bound to execute on the trigger.

Comment: @IAbstract Thank you. I will be looking into the Command object that is bound to execute on the trigger.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can only use animations in such action collections (so you could use a single frame animation). Also, if you disable on `MouseDown` your button might never execute.

As to why you cannot do that, i am not entirely sure, but `Setters` usually denote a state-dependent configuration, not an imperative action, so maybe that is why only animations are allowed.

Comment: Thank you. That answers my question.